# How many code with no two digits side by side are same?

Tags: combinatorics

A code consists of 5 digit numbers arranged from integers $0, 1, 2, ..., 9$. How many code with no two digits side by side are same?

I have tried to answer it as below.

First digit can filled by $0, 1, ...,9$ so it have $10$ options.

Second digit can filled by $0, 1, ...,9$ except the digit used in first digit, so it have $9$ options.

Third digit can filled by $0, 1, ...,9$ except the digit used in second digit, so it have $9$ options.

Fourth digit can filled by $0, 1, ...,9$ except the digit used in third digit, so it have $9$ options.

Fifth digit can filled by $0, 1, ...,9$ except the digit used in fourth digit, so it have $9$ options.

So, the number of code is
$$10\times 9^4.$$
I'm not sure with my answer. Is it right answer? If my answer is wrong, what the hint to be used for answer this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct.

If you have doubt, a generally good idea (esp. in combinatorics) is to try smaller examples. E.g. length-$3$ codes using just letters A,B,C. By your logic you should have $3 \times 2 \times 2 = 12$ such codes (out of $27$ possible). This is easy to check by hand:

AAA, AAB, AAC, **ABA**, ABB, **ABC**, **ACA**, **ACB**, ACC,

BAA, **BAB**, **BAC**, BBA, BBB, BBC, **BCA**, **BCB**, BCC,

CAA, **CAB**, **CAC**, **CBA**, CBB, **CBC**, CCA, CCB, CCC.